# Django queryset annotation filters (for max)

Tags: django, annotations, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    # model fields

class Table(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        Room, [...], related_name='tables'
    )

class Seat(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(
        Table, [...], related_name='seats'
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_vip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I would like to get the timestamp of the latest seat with a vip on it.

Getting the latest seat is easy like this:

```
Room.objects.all().annotate(latest_seat=Max('tables__seats__timestamp'))
```

But how do I filter this on is_vip=True only?

Comment: Should `Room`s without a vip seat be included?

Comment: No not in this case. But this is indeed a problem if a room has no vip seats, we do not get a timestamp. As the original question was answered I added a new one to fix this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64384258/django-annotation-case-when

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **`Q()`** expression

```
from django.db.models import Q

Room.objects.annotate(
    latest_seat=Max(
        'tables__seats__timestamp',
        filter=Q(tables__seats__is_vip=True))
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it should only be `Q` not `models.Q`, otherwise exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Yeah... it was a typo