# Django annotation case when

Tags: django, annotations, django-queryset

I have the following model:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    # model fields

class Table(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        Room, [...], related_name='tables'
    )
    preparation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)

class Seat(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(
        Table, [...], related_name='seats'
    )
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_vip = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The code itself checks that per room there is a maximum of one table with `preparation_time=None`. Which is always the `.last()` one in the queryset.

I would like to get the latest timestamp based on the following rules:

1.) If all tables of a room are prepared, return the latest `preparation_time` (the `preparation_time` of the latest table in the room)
2.) If there is a table without `preparation_time`, return the latest timestamp of a seat with a vip on it.

I am getting the latest seat for case 2 like this:

```
Room.objects.annotate(
    latest_activity=Max(
        'tables__seats__timestamp',
        filter=models.Q(tables__seats__is_vip=True))
)
```

Then I tried to implement the first rule like this:

```
.annotate(
    last_activity=Case(
        When(~Exists(Q(tables__preparation_time__isnull=True)),
             then=Max('tables__seats__timestamp', filter=Q(tables__seats__is_vip=True))
        ),
        default=Table.objects.filter(room=OuterRef('id')).last().preparation_time,
        output_field=DateTimeField()
)
```

For some reason this fails as I can not use the Q query in the exists.

What would be the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Your preperation_time field is DateTimeField or BooleanField?

Comment: @SerikzhanNaviy Thanks, got this wrong on typing, should be DateTimeField. Question is now updated.